# Add "selected" class to list item then disable "ahref" on the rest of list items in that specific list with jquery

Tags: jquery, list, select, button

I have a few divs that contain unordered lists. Inside those list-items I have buttons you can click. Is it possible to be able to click 1button, add a my class "selected" then kill the href on all list items in that ul? The goal is to be able to use a global function for multiple divs I have like below:

This is the structure of my HTML.

```
      <div id="dd" class="mywrap-dropdown-2" tabindex="2">Select
                 <ul class="dropdowner" id="coll-filter">
                      <li><a href="">All</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">White</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Blue</li>
                 </ul>
        </div> 



     <div id="dd" class="mywrap-dropdown-2" tabindex="2">Select
                 <ul class="dropdowner" id="coll-filter">
                      <li><a href="">Metal</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Chrome</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Wood</li>
                 </ul>
        </div>
```

Not sure how to go about this. This function is supposed to use on multiple divs "#dd" not just one.

Comment: Did my solution not answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will add `class="selected"` to the parent `<li>` of the first clicked anchor and then disable all further actions. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Y5x4/2/

```
$( '#dd' )
    .on( 'click', 'li', function( e )
        {
            e.preventDefault();             
        }
     )
     .on( 'click.runonce', 'li', function( e )
         {
              $( this ).addClass( 'selected' );

             $( '#dd' ).off( 'click.runonce' );
         }
     );
```

Edit: Updated the example. Old code: http://jsfiddle.net/9Y5x4/1/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle raray. Once a button is clicked you can no longer click on any other buttons. So once one is clicked all the rest in that un-ordered list are disable.

Comment: You could remove the other options of the UL like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eaTC5/1/ - Also, note that ID's have to be unique in HTML

Comment: The idea is to remove the "ahref" not remove the entire button

Comment: Let's see if we can get to using a common vocabulary so things are more clear. In your HTML there are no buttons. There are list-items and anchors. I'll update the example to better reflect what I think you're going for, but understand that I can only provide an example of how to do this, not fully transportable code.